# Apps deleted in iTunes 11 not removed from iPhone & iPad

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipad, data-synchronization

In previous versions of iTunes I could delete an app and this deletion would propagate to all devices on synchronization.  It no longer seems to be the case in iTunes 11.0.2.  I can delete the app from iTunes, but the app isn't deleted from my iPhone or iPad on synchronization.  Is this a new feature or a bug?  Is there a configuration option to change this?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like new feature since you can manage applications on your iDevice without changing others. This is way like iPhone Configuration Utility always do.